# SQL: sum the number of rows within a partition for a rolling week window where a specific condition is met

Tags: sql, presto

Goal: to get a count of people who fall under target for one week, two weeks, three weeks and four weeks in a rolling 4-week window.

The idea would be to use an analytical function that partitions by work week (WW) to get a count of people who fall under target for any given week. A person does not have to be consecutively under target for numerous weeks. If a person falls under target for at least one week, regardless of which work week it is, then count it. If they fall under target for any two weeks, count that and so on.

IF(score < 50, 1, 0) AS target.

```
week      person  target
WW 31     name_x    1
WW 31     name_y    1
WW 31     name_z    0
--------------------
WW 32     name_x    1
WW 32     name_y    1
WW 32     name_z    0
--------------------
WW 33     name_x    0
WW 33     name_y    1
WW 33     name_z    0
--------------------
WW 34     name_x    1
WW 34     name_y    1
WW 34     name_z    0
```

Desired output would be a table from which I could build a visualization like this, where the y axis is a line counting the number of people who fall under target for 1, 2, 3, and 4 weeks.
[VISUALIZATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn3Xn.png)

I've tried something like this

`SUM(CASE WHEN target = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY week)`

This works for calculating the people under target for at least one week, but I am struggling on how to do it for people who fall under target for at least 2, 3, or 4 weeks.

Comment: Your sample data has no date or indication of week.  How is that calculated?

Comment: I left some details out but essentially I'm working with a 4 week rolling window where the week (1-52) changes as we move through time. I used letters to denote the week just to keep it visually simple. Since this is a rolling window, in my previous temp table I uses a dense_row analytical function to transform the first week in the window to 1, the last week in the window to 4. In my sample data, 1 = A, D = 4. I thought it'd look so busy with so many numbers.

Comment: I've updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check previous weeks target with `LAG()` [Window Function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html):

> **lag(x[, offset[, default_value]]) → [same as input]**
>
> Returns the value
> at offset rows before the current row in the window Offsets start at
> 0, which is the current row. The offset can be any scalar expression.
> The default offset is 1. If the offset is null or larger than the
> window, the default_value is returned, or if it is not specified null
> is returned.

A query similar to this should get you the desired result:

```
with data_table as
(
   select week, person, target
   ,LAG(target,1,null)OVER(PARTITION BY person ORDER BY week) target_1w_ago
   ,LAG(target,2,null)OVER(PARTITION BY person ORDER BY week) target_2w_ago
   ,LAG(target,3,null)OVER(PARTITION BY person ORDER BY week) target_3w_ago
   from table
)
select week
,sum(target) "Weeks under 1"
,sum(case when target=1 and target_1w_ago=1 then 1 else 0 end) "Weeks under 2"
,sum(case when target=1 and target_1w_ago=1 and target_2w_ago=1 then 1 else 0 end) "Weeks under 3"
,sum(case when target=1 and target_1w_ago=1 and target_2w_ago=1 and target_3w_ago=1 then 1 else 0 end) "Weeks under 4"
from data_table
group by week
order by week
```